# Use CreateThread with a lambda

Tags: c++, winapi

Just experimenting, but I was wondering if it's possible to make this code work (as in compile):

```
void main() {
    int number = 5;

    DWORD(*dontThreadOnMe)(PVOID) = [](PVOID data) {
        int value = *(int*) data;

        cout << value << endl;
        cout << "This callback executed successsfully" << endl;
    };

    CreateThread(NULL, NULL, dontThreadOnMe, &number, NULL, NULL);
    cin.get();
}
```

I have this nagging suspicion that because the standard signature for a `LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE` callback is `DWORD WINAPI Callback(PVOID)` I won't be able to get this to compile without the added (but grammatically illegal) `WINAPI` tag. Speaking of which, what exactly are the `WINAPI` and `CALLBACK` (for say `WndProc`) attributes? I've never really understood why in certain circumstances you could have multiple attributes on a function.

Comment: `main` is required to have `int` as a return type. You'd also need a `__stdcall` lambda, which isn't possible. You can wrap it to take a lambda (or anything), though, or just use `<thread>`.

Comment: Since you're obviously using C++11, why not just use `std::thread` which is portable and integrates well with lambdas, instead of the platform-specific `CreateThread`?

Comment: I only just started learning. But I'll look into that. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, works like a charm!

Comment: This may work for simple cases, but if the thread is taking longer there might be issues. Since the lambda gets cleaned when the parent function ends, it limits the CreateThread and lambda usage a lot.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually this is possible with Visual C++ 2012 and above; to quote from [Microsoft's list of C++ feature support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx):

> Additionally in Visual C++ in Visual Studio 2012, stateless lambdas
>   are convertible to function pointers. ... we've made stateless
>   lambdas convertible to function pointers that have arbitrary calling
>   conventions. This is important when you are using APIs that expect
>   things like __stdcall function pointers

So in Visual C++ 2012 you can do something like:

```
unsigned int id;
HANDLE hThread = reinterpret_cast<HANDLE>(_beginthreadex(0, 0,
    [](void* pData) -> unsigned int {
        // I'm a thread!
        return 0;
    }, pThreadData, 0, &id));
```

This means you can also use lambdas with other API functions that expect callback functions (things like `EnumWindows()` and `CreateDialogParam()`, for example).

Comment: Ah hah! I long wondered how this would work considering the x86 ABI requires `__stdcall` for (most) of its thread entry-points (x64 does not really matter). Thank you for pointing this out, **+1**

Answer (score 3):

You can make things a little less wordy using auto :)

```
auto dontThreadOnMe = [](LPVOID data) -> DWORD {
    int value = *(int*)data;
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "This callback executed successsfully" << std::endl;
    return 0; //don't forget your return code!
};

int number = 42;
auto thread = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, dontThreadOnMe, &number, 0, nullptr);
```

Or, for the copy paste addicts who find this answer later on ;), this is all you need:

```
auto work = [](LPVOID data) -> DWORD { return 0; };
int thread_param = 42;
auto thread = CreateThread(nullptr, 0, work, &thread_param, 0, nullptr);
```

Comment: the compiler says i cant cast a lambda into an LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE

Answer (score 3):

At least in current<sup>*</sup> versions of Mingw64 you can specify the calling convention of a lambda function, as in `[]() WINAPI {}`:

```
CreateThread(
    nullptr, // lpThreadAttributes
    0,       // dwStackSize
    [](void *param) WINAPI -> DWORD { // lpStartAddress
        (void) param;
        return 0;
    },
    nullptr, // lpParameter
    0,       // dwCreationFlags
    nullptr  // lpThreadId
);
```

*) Tested with i686-w64-mingw32-g++-win32 (GCC) 6.3.0 20170516. Earlier version may work, too.